# NodeJs exec with ssh not working with forever

Tags: node.js, ssh, exec, forever

below is the code with is working fine with node test.js command. but whenever i am trying to run test.js with forever utility it wont work.

```
var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('bash');
terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Sending stdin to terminal');
    terminal.stdin.write("whomi\n");
    terminal.stdin.write("sudo ssh instance-solr-1.us-central1-b.versatile-nomad-126504 \"sudo su | . /root/file
.sh >>/dev/null 2>/dev/null\" &\n");
    console.log('Ending terminal session');
    terminal.stdin.end();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I think the command is `whoami`.

Comment: its just for testing purpose i have added whomi and \n is required at end of each command as i am using stdin.write

Comment: I'm not sure that `sudo` will work like that since it will expect a tty, which will not be the case when spawning `bash` with the default `stdio` option (which is to create a pipe for all file descriptors). FWIW this is unrelated, but you may be interested in trying/using the [`ssh2`](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) module instead of spawning a new process.

Comment: Hi mscdex, thanks for your reply.. i figure out the issue its just because of tty it wont work without stdio so i have spawn child process detached with parent and which ignore stdio.. and now its working fine in background ..